# Unable to find property declaration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

Is `Unable to find property declaration 'someProperty'` a crash?

There are logs in our server about this crash but I cannot reproduce the crash. So, I'm asking if this is really a crash or just an error log? And if it is crash, do devices really crash?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be a build time warning or error, not run time.

Comment: Can you post more of the error log?

Comment: I checked the call stack and it seems like it happened on runtime. The time spent before the app crash is 394.91

Answer (score 0):

Are you using *Objection Framework*? If so, there is most likely a problem with a dependency injection. Objection is not finding a property that should be registered or is required.

I think you are only seeing it in logs (and not as a build error) because Objection lazily insantiates dependencies.

... and yes, iOS apps on physical devices do crash :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `Objection Framework`. Does the app crash when this occur because I can't reproduce the crash? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it will crash. Objection will throw an exception with this message when a property is not found, but I'm not sure how that exception is managed. Why don't you double-check the dependencies you specify with Objection?

Comment: I already double check the classes that use objection. Should it be like this?
 
//.h
property someProperty
 
// .m
synthesize someProperty = _someProperty

Answer (score 0):

Your 'someProperty' is not available as outlet in Connection Inspector in the right side of main storyboard.Check this properly and delete this one.This may be the reason of crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is a runtime crash. I simulated this on Xcode. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the *Objection Framework*,

`objection_requires` must be used to declare your dependencies. Ensure that the dependencies list matches the properties you've declared and synthesized.